github enable actions only for protected branches
I am trying to find a way by which i can disable github actions on a set of branches,(and not by adding if conditions in the workflow files, which can be edited by a developer.)
We have a github repo on which we do manage the environments using infra structure as code. We allow developers to raise PR from different branches to the main, which is a protected branch.
Since workflows can be modified and ran against any branch by a developer, the system can be now miss used to deploy without the PR itself.
Wonder are there anyway i can disable workflows, through settings, and allow only protected branches to be enabled for workflows.
Looking for opinion, if anyone had similar problems, and how did they handle this situation.

If you use Environments for the deployment (and store the secrets there), you can use its source branch features to ensure only protected branches get access to the environments.

You can add if condition in workflow files for specific branches, and create a ruleset for same branches which does not allow pushes to those files.
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets#:~:text=allow%20you%20to%3A-,Restrict%20file%20paths,-%3A%20Prevent%20commits%20that

You can add if condition in workflow files for specific branches, then create a ruleset for same branches which does not allow pushes to those files. here is reference to the doc

Still a person can commit a new workflow to thier branch and run the workflow. I want to make sure only a subset of branch allowed to run workflows.

I think protected branches are the way, but which is a premium feature.

Maybe I was not enough clear, I mean if admin adds ruleset for specific branches which does not allow pushes to .github folder/files, new actions and actions modifications will be prohibited.
